# http request terminating early

Tags: web-hosting, apache, http

I noticed that on some of my sites, images were occasionally not getting downloaded fully.
After a bit of investigation it appears that it is not restricted to images - .css, .js etc were also occasionally terminating early. The faults appear to be random.

When I use the debug/proxy tool Fiddler2 reports that fewer bytes have been received than were requested. Firebug reports "Image corrupt or truncated".

Obviously this is mainly a concern between me and my hosting company. However despite many emails they have not been able to get to the bottom of it. Transfer to another hosting company is obviously an option but is really a last resort.

Has anyone seen this kind of thing before or can anyone suggest what might be causing it. Or any apache setting or something that I can ask them to check out. Will apache log this kind of error - they havent been able to provide me with any logs, but if I know exactly where things have been logged, maybe I can prompt them in to action.

**EDIT: More data as requested by commenters..**

I created a test page. It is pure HTML and embeds 9 images each of size between 4 and 6MB. This is a very large amount of data. I found having so much data speeded up the occurrence of faults which makes benchmarking easier. As a control, I run the same test on the server of another hosting company that I have access to - I never get faults when running on this other host.

It is on shared hosting.

I have tested it on FF, IE & Chrome.

**EDIT - DETAILS OF HEADERS ETC ...**

(In case your wondering, this version of the test is not pure HTML but has a small amount of PHP added to to prevent caching.)

LiveHeaders o/p...
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B93lksnTC7_cYVhQT2lMbms5Mm8/edit

What you see in Firefox...
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B93lksnTC7_ceHBSbmhXWHhXdlk/edit

What Firebug logs...
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B93lksnTC7_cOEdmeU1lMkh4UE0/edit

If you have difficulty getting into google docs - alternative...
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F8DE44BC9AC7FD6!107&authkey=!AAXurFZleJE5okQ

As you can see the images that failed were:
DSC_0046_0.JPG
DSC_0232_0.JPG

**EDIT - UPDATE**

I've noticed that it gets worse if I simultaneously run several copies of the test. (And running several copies of the test on the control host still passes.) Further suggesting that if the server gets too many requests it might be terminating some requests early or something.

Comment: Is your site doing a lot server-side in order to generate your pages? Do you experience the same issue when serving a static version of your page?

Comment: It is pure HTML. No PHP or anything. (I created a test page that has 9 large images in it).

Comment: If it's a static HTML page then it does suggest there's a problem with your host. If it's a shared server then maybe it's under heavy load from other users (a guess)?! How large are your images/page?

Comment: @w3d - I have appended more details to the question. The test page I use is very large - takes about 1 minute to complete downloading everything. You've got me worried - could my browser or something be giving up instead and confusing the issue (though then surely firebug would not report an error?)

Comment: look into the apache error log for clues

Comment: @Gaia where is this stored please? The only thing I have found is under /statistics/logs/error_log but there is nothing relevant in here. I have asked the host provider if there are any more logs I can look at but the declined to reply (they seem to be going giving up on it)

Comment: @spiderplant0 if you are on shared hosting your hosting provider should allow you to access the error_log for your vhost. If they are NOT letting you access that then you might as well assume they are a crappy hosting company that is overselling their servers, hence the problem you are having (server overload is causing incomplete requests)

Comment: @Gaia. The thing is I dont know what the server error log is supposed to look like.
In my error_log file the only errors I have are...
"Directory index forbidden by Options directive"
"File does not exist: [is refering here to the robots.txt]"
Does this look like the error log you were referring to?

Comment: if it doesnt begin with [Wed Oct 11 14:32:52 2000] you are not seeing the log, maybe just a filtered version of it. still, this type of error will only be shown in the main log. who is the hosting company?

Comment: It does begin with this date string (I just stripped it out for brevity). Company is http://www.unlimitedwebhosting.co.uk

Comment: have you checked the headers sent with the page? and with each image? you can do that with, for instance, with the live http headers for firefox. If you can post the headers for the page you created and then the headers for each image independently, we can evaluate that.

Comment: @PatomaS Done - see edited question

Comment: there seems to be a problem with google docs, it presents an error popup in front of your second and third links.

Comment: @PatomaS Added link to skydrive folder - contains the 3 files

Comment: do you have any information about the server/hosting?is it a big company? is a dedicated server for you? is a shared plan? ...?

Comment: unlimitedwebhosting.co.uk It seems to be quite well known. Its quite cheap (which is probably the root of the problem).  It is shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there seems to be a problem with caching and the freshness of the information, in this case, the images, but I still don't have a clear answer.

In the headers docs you posted, you can see a response header with a 206 code, that means that the server is responding to a request for partial content, the question is why is it happening.

The first thing you should try, is add an etag to all files, that should help, you can do that with this code in your .htaccess

```
FileETag All
```

If you can also set the cache-control, it will be of help also, you can do it in your .htaccess with a code like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset Cache-Control
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, s-maxage=31536000"
        Header set Pragma "cache"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Try those changes to see if the situation improves, then if you can log the headers again, it and paste it, we can check the differences.

If you don't like those values, you can change them, but hose should be good for some tests.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the "206" One of the file that failed (DSC_0232_0.JPG) seems to have 3 entries. And this is the one that has the 206

Comment: Re-ran with your .htaccess. Results here: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F8DE44BC9AC7FD6!114&authkey=!AAYWLomWK09F3Og  Seems very similar to before. Again one of the images appears 3 times with a 206 for one of them (DSC_0079.JPG) By the way the reason I had no cache on was to simulate first time visiting at this URL

Comment: I can imagine, also that was the reason I asked to activate cache, to see the reaction of the server with a cached image, if it really sent it well the first time should answer with 304 and you shouldn't have seen a new range request